# Optional normal mapping in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, normals

I am trying to figure out how to deal with materials that may or may not have a normal map and if not tell the shader to use the vertex normal. The code right now looks like this:

```
// retrieve the normal from the normal map
gNormal = texture(normalMap, uv);
gNormal = normalize(gNormal * 2.0 - 1.0);
gNormal = vec4(normalize(TBN * gNormal.xyz), 1.0);

// TODO: figure out a way to toggle normal mapping
//gNormal = vec4(normalize(normal), 1.0);
```

The most common solution is procedurally generating shaders and switching on the fly but that is a complex topic in itself. Are there any other options besides passing in a `uniform bool` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to always use a normal map. The simplest normal map is a 1x1 texture with 1 normal vector - for instance (0, 0, 1).
With this solution, you do not need branching in the shader.

Comment: That would mean I can't use the vertex normal right?

Comment: @NicovanBentum Yes. The normal vector from the map is transformed by `TBN`. `TBN * vec3(0, 0, 1)` is the z axis of `TBN`, which is the normal vector (`N`).